# Apply particle system (Beta 2.80)

Tags: modifiers

I have a particle system on a sphere. The particles are another object (small spikes). I supposed that **convert** in the modifier panel would apply it to my object. But when I export as an .fbx or .obj and import it again the particles on the sphere are missing …
So either I am doing something wrong or the **convert** button doesn’t work.

Can someone help me?

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny The modifier convert doesn’t work

Comment: I see, tried it and you are right, the function does nothing. It's probably not yet implemented, the beta is still buggy. You can use the Help>Report A Bug option in the 2.8 menus to let developers know if they are not aware and get it fixed.